# why will for loop not recognize || operator?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, operator-keyword

I'm doing exercise problems without a teacher, so I'm coming to the internet for help.

I am trying to do this problem:

> Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket". That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

However, I am running into a problem when I try to differentiate between vowels and consonants. This is what I have:

```
function translate(text){
var newText;
if (!(text.charAt(0) ==  "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")){
    newText = text.charAt(0) + "o" + text.charAt(0);
    } else {
        newText = text.charAt(0);
    }
for (var i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
    if (!(text.charAt(i) ==  "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")){
        newText += text.charAt(i) + "o" + text.charAt(i);
    } else {
        newText += text.charAt(i);
    }
} 
console.log(newText);
}

translate("hello this is");
```

Could anyone explain why the || operator is not working? I think that would fix the issues I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the OR operator; each condition needs to be complete. Try this:

```
if (!(text.charAt(0) == "a"
    || text.charAt(0) == "e"
    || text.charAt(0) == "i"
    || text.charAt(0) == "o" 
    || text.charAt(0) == "u") ){
```

As an alternative (since this can get unwieldy quickly), you can store vowels in a separate array, then check to see if the given character is in the array.

```
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
if(vowels.indexOf(text.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) === -1) {
    // Vanna, I'd like to buy a vowel
}
else {
    // Consonant
}
```

Comment: Or you know.. `!"aeiou".split("").some(function(el){ return text[0] === el;})`

Comment: Wow, thanks @ChrisForrence! That was the easiest fix. I'll check it when it lets me (in about 8 minutes).

Comment: Or, you know... `!/[aeiou]/.test(text[0])`

Comment: Ben, you're correct (as long as you remember to make it handle upper- and lower-case). However, let's start at a more basic level for now. But @user2373912, keep in mind that there are more efficient ways to do something like this, and for fun, you should try and find out _how_ Ben's first method works